# if field is null display none in sitecore

Tags: javascript, c#, sitecore

This is within Sitecore 7.2 and C#.

I am using 3 fields within 1 div and I can't figure out how to to display each when a field is entered. So my fields are steak, bacon and eggs. All of them are rich text editor's. So let's say steak is loaded when page is loaded. What do I do when a user enters text into bacon or eggs, so that it turns steak to display: none; and shows what the user has inputted into the field? I am not sure if this is a javascript thing or a back-end C# thing.

Assume I have a template working along with the control created in Sitecore with the fields desired and when someone enters in the field and publishes it shows up in HTML.

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="steak" id="steak"><sc:FieldRenderer FieldName="Steak" runat="server"  /></div>
        <div class="bacon" id="bacon"><sc:FieldRenderer FieldName="Bacon" runat="server"  /></div>
        <div class="eggs id="eggs"><sc:FieldRenderer FieldName="Eggs" runat="server"  /></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Now I haven't any handler in this code, which implement functionality as you described

Comment: Are you looking to only show the wrapping div around the field if the field is populated?

Comment: Pretend steak class is visible while bacon and eggs are hidden on page load. When bacon or eggs field is filled , it becomes visible and steak is hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the class and id attributes (style it instead as `.container div`) you could use the enclosing tag property of the fieldrenderer:

```
<div class="container">
  <sc:FieldRenderer FieldName="Steak" EnclosingTag="div" runat="server" />
  <sc:FieldRenderer FieldName="Bacon" EnclosingTag="div" runat="server" />
  <sc:FieldRenderer FieldName="Eggs" EnclosingTag="div" runat="server" />
</div>
```

If the field is populated then the text will be wrapped with a div tag, otherwise nothing will be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `<asp:PlaceHolder/>` control wrapped around each of your `<div>`s to achieve this:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder Visible='<%#!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Sitecore.Context.Item["Steak"])%>' runat="server">
   <div class="steak">
      <sc:FieldRenderer FieldName="Steak" runat="server"></sc:FieldRenderer>
   </div>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

I've shown setting the visibility in the ascx markup here, but you could easily do it from code-behind if you prefer.  Also, you should ideally check for page-editing mode as well to ensure that the placeholder is always shown when in page editor mode (this involves checking the property `Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditorEditing`).

Comment: I'll try this but what happens when two or more fields are populated? How do I make sure that if bacon or eggs field is populated, that it is visible while steak remains hidden?

Comment: You'd do it for each field. That is, you'd have a separate placeholder for each field. That said jammykams answer is probably the better way of doing it.

Comment: As jammykams pointed out the EnclosingTag is better approach however that will not set the class attribute.  Check out this blog post how to handle that.  http://sitecoreclimber.wordpress.com/2014/10/27/how-to-set-css-class-on-fieldrenderer/